# Correct approach to play a multiple files simultaneously using Core Audio

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-audio

I've developed a model, which plays up to 10 tracks with a number of clips on each using **AVFoundation**.
Still I don't like the performance and sound corruption in deed.

I read documentation of **Core Audio** and tried out some samples.
Some plays only 1 file using **AU Generator** (**AudioFilePlayer** subtype).
Those samples where 2 files are playing use **MultichannelMixer** and custom buffers to render audio data.

Could I use MultichannelMixer and connect multiple **Generators** (**AudioFilePlayer**) to its nodes?
Or the best way is to render data by myself?

*Thanks in advance!*

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question? I'm trying to play back two files via two separate AudioFilePlayer AUs but it's not working.

Comment: No, I don't. I stacked on that implementation. The thing is, you don't need to use AudioFilePlayer to play 2 files. You have to get data of each audio file and mix it using MultichannelMixer.

Comment: Right, I'm feeding my filePlayer units into the mixer. The filePlayer units seems simpler to implement than opening the file, filling buffers and doing it all 'manually'. I received some tips I'm going to try out later tonight. I'll let you know if they work.